# Typescript and mongoose: saving to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have the following app saving into memory repo. I connected a local mongodb but I have issues saving the posted data into mongodb.
When the app is saving to the memory it works just fine and I can use curl to display the array of different event saved there. I now would like to make it save into my DB so I can then work with the data saved and I couldn't find any clear tutorial on that
Can someone advice how it should be done?
Mongodb schema:

```
import { mongoose } from '././http'

const CompetitionSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  place: String,
  time: String,
  subscriptions: [],
  date: new Date(),
  cost: {
    currency: String,
    amount: Number,
  },
})

export const CompetitionModel = mongoose.model(
  'CompetitionModel',
  CompetitionSchema,
)

export default CompetitionSchema
```

http:

```
export const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/CompetitionEvent')
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'An error has occured: '))
db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Connected to Mongodb')
})

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get('/events', (_req: any, res: any) => {
  res.send(eventApplication.getAll())
})

app.post('/event', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  await eventApplication.createAnEvent(req.body)
  res.json({
    success: true,
  })
})

app.listen(8000)
```

in memory and mongodb repository

```
export interface EventRepositoryInterface {
  // will require ansyc call will have return promise of all below - refactor needed
  save: (event: CompetitionEvent) => void
  getById: (id: string) => CompetitionEvent | undefined
  getAll: () => CompetitionEvent[]
}

export class InMemoryEventRepository implements EventRepositoryInterface {
  constructor(private events: CompetitionEvent[] = []) {}

  public save = (event: CompetitionEvent) =>
    (this.events = [...this.events, event])
  public getById = (id: string) => this.events.find((e) => e.id === id)
  public getAll = () => this.events
}

export class MongoCompetitionEventRepository
  implements EventRepositoryInterface {
  constructor(private events: CompetitionEvent[] = []) {}

  //here event should go to DB and NOT in the array memory
  public save = (event: CompetitionEvent) =>
    (this.events = [...this.events, event])
  public getById = (id: string) => this.events.find((e) => e.id === id)
  public getAll = () => this.events
}
```

Please let me know if something is missing I'll edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have done here is connected to the local MongoDB now you will have to login to the MongoDB website i.e,[here](https://account.mongodb.com/account/login), after logging in the very first thing to do is create a user to access the db/collections, click on **Database Access**, add a user, use the authentication mode as password to create the user, next you will have to whitelist your IP address to do that click on **Network Access** and add either your IP Address or `0.0.0.0/0`(which basically means all/any IP address including yours can access this DB), after that you will have to create a new DB, inside the DB you will have to create collections, to do this click on **Clusters**, *Collection* and create your db from there, finally to complete it all you will need to connect to the DB, for this click on **Clusters**, *Connect* and choose either the *Connect Application* or the *Connect using MongoDB Compass* option this will give you the connection URL looking like this:-

---

`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-gd3lq.mongodb.net/test`

---

for the **MongoDB compass** option

---

`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-gd3lq.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

---

and like this for **Connect Application** option over here you will have to change the `<username>:<password>` with the username and password used to create the user in **Database Access** also change the `<dbname>` with your actual DB name.
In your case where you have `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/CompetitionEvent')` you have to replace it with your connection URL.

References:-

- https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
- https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/
- https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to keep it on my local machine on purpose. Not to store any data online. 
My question is more how to get my MongoCompetitionEventRepository to save to the local database rather than to the memory :)